# How to check for model1.field where model1 has many to many relationship model2

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a model `question` , `submissions` , `users`

`submissions` has many to many relationship with `users` and `questions`

So basically `submissions` has the following fields:

```
questions
users
time
score
is_solved
```

When displaying questions to the user I am also displaying whether that particular question has been solved by the user or not. So, if `is_solved` is `true` I will display "solved"

I am returning all `questions` to my html page as well as all the `submissions` user has made and I'm using a loop

```
for question in questions
    // check if solved
         // display solved
    // else do nothing
end for
```

My question is how do I check for `submissions.solved` for each `question` in the loop